# Remove files from jar archive with exclusion

Tags: linux, bash, sh

`zip -d foo/bar/abc.jar "qwe/!(da-man*)xml"`

When trying to remove file from jar with Shell Pathname Expansion I get

> zip error: Nothing to do!

I have also tried

`zip -d foo/bar/abc.jar qwe/\!\(da-man\*\)xml`

what doesn't work.

But `zip -d foo/bar/abc.jar qwe/*xml` works correctly.

What the reason?

Answer (score 1):

That is because you are trying to find files using **regex** instead of **file globbing**. Try this one:

First see if files are matching:

```
jar tf foo/bar/abc.jar | grep "qwe/!(da-man*)xml"
```

if matches then delete them:

```
jar tf foo/bar/abc.jar | grep "qwe/!(da-man*)xml" | xargs zip -d foo/bar/abc.jar
```